# Determining how many rows, and how many items per row

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

This isn't a complicated problem, but I can't for whatever reason think of a simple way to do this with the modulus operator.  Basically I have a collection of N items and I want to display them in a grid.

I can display a maximum of 3 entries across and infinite vertically; they are not fixed width...So If I have 2 items they get displayed like that `[1][2]`.  If I have 4 items they get displayed stacked like this:

```
[1][2]
[3][4]
```

If I have 5 items it should look like this:

```
[ 1 ][ 2]
[3][4][5]
```

Seven items is slightly more complicated:

```
[ 1 ][ 2]
[ 3 ][ 4]
[5][6][7]
```

This is one of those things where if I slept on it, it would be brain dead obvious in the morning, but all I can think about doing involves complicated loops and state variables.  There has to be an easier way.

I'm doing this in C# but I doubt the language matters.

Comment: Is another criteria that the last row be fully populated?  Otherwise, why wouldn't the 7 items be

1 2 3 \n 4 5 6 \n 7

Comment: why don't you just put 3 in each row (mod 3 all the way down) and put the remaining 1 or 2 in the last row?

Comment: @SimonC: yes the idea is to not have sparse rows.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me whether you wanted to minimize rows, but I assumed so. For example, any multiple of 6 items could have all rows of two items or all rows of three items. Which do you prefer? Similarly, larger even numbers of items (such as 10, 26, or 50) could be displayed with two items per row, or you could minimize the number of rows by using as many three-item rows as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By maximizing the number of rows that have three items, you can minimize the total number of rows. Thus six items would be grouped as two rows of 3 rather than three rows of 2:

```
[1][2][3]
[4][5][6]
```

and ten items would be grouped as two rows of 2 and two rows of 3 rather than five rows of 2:

```
[ 1 ][ 2 ]
[ 3 ][ 4 ]
[5][6][7 ]
[8][9][10]
```

If you want rows with two items first, then you keep peeling off two items until the remaining items are divisible by 3. As you go through the loop, you need to keep track of the number of remaining items using an index or whatnot.

In your loop to populate each row, you can check these conditions:

```
//logic within loop iteration
if (remaining % 3 == 0) //take remaining in threes; break the loop
else if (remaining >= 4) //take two items, leaving two or more remaining
else //take remaining items, which will be two or three; break the loop
```

If we walk through the example of 10 items, the process would go as follows:

1. 10 items remaining. 10 % 3 != 0. Since 10 > 4, take two items.
2. 8 items remaining. 8 % 3 != 0. Since 8 > 4, take two items.
3. 6 items remaining. 6 % 3 = 0. Take those 6 items in groups of three.

To go to your example of 7 items:

1. 7 items remaining. 7 % 3 != 0. Since 7 > 4, take two items.
2. 5 items remaining. 5 % 3 != 0. Since 5 > 4, take two items.
3. 3 items remaining. 3 % 3 = 0. Take those 3 items as a group.

And here's the result for 4 items:

1. 4 items remaining. 4 % 3 != 0. Since remaining = 4, take two items.
2. 2 items remaining. 2 % 3 != 0. 2 < 4. Fall to else condition, take remaining items.

I think that'll work. At least, at 12:30 a.m. it seems like it should work.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense and goes along with my original looping idea but I had the logic stuff all hosed. This is gonna be one of those problems where it gets hacked together now and fixed tomorrow when its not 12:30 am; I'm in the same boat :).

Comment: You're welcome. This was a fun little problem. Better now than 4 a.m. If it was 4 a.m. I'd be halfway into an explanation that combines LINQ, generics, and aesthetic layouts for photo albums. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((list.Count % 2) == 0)
{
 //Display all as [][]
                  [][]
}
else
{
//Display all as    [][]
                    [][]
//Display last 3 as [][][]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, given that: a) the objective is to minimize the number of rows, b) a row cannot have more than 3 items, c) a row should have 3 items if possible, and d) you cannot have a row with a single item unless it is the only item, I would say the algorithm goes as follows:

1. If there is only one item, it will be alone in its own row; done.
2. Calculate the 'tentative' number of rows by dividing the number of items by 3.
3. If the remainder (N % 3) is 0, then all rows will have 3 items.
4. If the remainder is 1, then there will be an additional row, and the last 2 rows will only have 2 items each.
5. If the remainder is 2, then there will be an additional row, and it will only have 2 items.

This algorithm will produce a slightly different format from the one you were envisioning, (the 3-item rows will be at the top, the 2-item rows will be at the bottom,) but it satisfies the constraints. If you need the 2-item rows to be at the top, you can modify it.

Comment: IF I ahve 8 items, it should go [1][2] \n [3][4][5] \n [6][7][8]. The main problem I'm having is that I'm trying to figure out the number of items in the row where the nth element element is; all while I iterate over the n elements.

Comment: You have confused me now. Why `[1][2] \n [3][4][5] \n [6][7][8]` and not `[1][2] \n [3][4] \n [5][6] \n [7][8]`?  What is the rule for deciding the format?  You need to establish the rule and spell it out accurately before anyone can provide any helpful answers.

Comment: The objective is to minimize the number of rows.  A row cannot have more than 3 items and should seek to have the highest number of items per row.

Answer (score 1):

How about pseudo-code

```
if n mod 3 = 1
  first 2 rows have 2 items each (assuming n >= 4)
  all remaining rows have 3 items

else if n mod 3 = 2
  first row has 2 items
  all remaining rows have 3 items

else
  all rows have 3 items
```